# Is there any Java equivalent of EXT.NET framework?

Tags: java, extjs, ext.net

I was impressed by EXT.NET frameworks with lots of controls and usage of EXT.js. Is there a similar framework like EXT.NET but for Java side of technologies ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at ExtGxt, its based on Java and GWT. Complete server side coding, after compilation its converted to java script. Easy for people with good Java knowledge.

[ExtGxt from Sencha](http://www.sencha.com/products/gxt/)

Comment: seems like it is not supporting latest version of extjs.

Answer (score 1):

not yet (for controls). C # is a good package a lot of control.But I think that the control is not so important for a real developer.
java there are many open source framework framework. C # control, I think it is only on the surface, easy to use, VS2010 is indeed a good development tool.
Strut2 Hibernate Spring and so on.
Sorry,Google translate.